# Loading Bootstrap in Joomla - JUI or local copy?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm creating a template for Joomla 3.x using Bootstrap. I am aware of the fact that Bootstrap can be loaded or unloaded selectively. But I am torn as whether to use the built in JUI version or a local copy bundled with my template. Here's the pros and cons as I see them...

Using the JUI version:

1. Unknown version
2. Could change at any time in the future - for example to Bootstrap version 3 and break my template
3. Consistent with the version used by the latest and upcoming extensions

Using a Template (local) Version:

1. Controllable and static - no surprises
2. Might not benefit from any Bootstrap "fixes" the Joomla guys have added

Does anybody have any experiences or advice for me? Should I go with JUI version or load my own? Anybody know how long Joomla plan on keeping the current version of Bootstrap?

And, just to be certain, I am right in saying that versions of Joomla prior to version 3 wont have Boostrap by default and so my template would not be backwards compatible without loading my own version anyway right?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap will most likely be used for Joomla in the long term. It all depends on which version of Bootstrap you want to use to be honest. Joomla 3.x uses Bootstrap 2.x and the latest version of it is 3.0.0 which is rather a big difference in design.

If you plan in using Bootstrap 3, then you will need to include it with the template. If you plan on using 2.x, then it might be an idea to have a parameter so the user can select whether they load it from your template or from the Joomla core.

Some may say this is pretty pointless, however it's always good to have an option, just incase some users may have edited the core Bootstrap files or even removed them for some odd reason.

And yes, you're right in saying that versions of Joomla prior to version 3 wont have Boostrap by default, so even more of a reason to provide a parameter, as I gather you're making a template for Joomla 2.5 and 3.x

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I intend the template to work in both 2.5 and 3.1 so I suppose I have to include it. I like your idea of setting and unsetting using a parameter though - that's a great idea. I am using Bootstrap 2.x  was more worried that within 12 months the current version of Joomla may switch to Bootstrap 3 and basically render my template useless. Do you know if when unsetting Bootstrap I have to unset each file separately like this... unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);   and if so where I can find a full list of the Boostrap files I need to unset? Thanks

Comment: why would you want to unset the bootstrap files?

Comment: Well, the way I see it, the only way to have my template backwards compatible to version Joomla 2.5 is to include my own version of Bootstrap - therefore, to avoid conflict I would want to unset bootstrap from also being dragged in from the JUI or else I'd be doubling up right?

Comment: To clarify, I mean if I give the option to include my version of bootstrap instead of Joomla's own from its JUI, I would have to add the ability to unset the joomla version of Boostrap or else the template would then be loading the Joomla Bootstrap and its own version as well - which would be redundant and just slow loading.

Comment: The problem with adding backward compatibility for Bootstrap is that a classes have been removed so if might be better off having a separate template or ensuring that those classes are not used. Also ensure you don't use any newly added features in Bootstrap 3 as they won't work with 2. Other than that, you shouldn't have a problem with compatibility as it's will simply be styling changes

Comment: I've given this a more though recently. There's a big discussion going on Joomla UX. But Lodder you are right here that at present the safest option is not to use classes removed from Bootstrap 3